# R remove string after second underscore

Tags: r, string, substring

This is a very basic question, but I cannot find a clear answer... How do you remove everything after the second underscore. Thanks!

```
Please_remove_this_part
```

desired output:

```
Please_remove
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would frame the problem as extracting everything before the 2nd underscore:

```
x = "Please_remove_this_part"
stringr::str_extract(x, "[^_]*_[^_]*")
# [1] "Please_remove"
```

Explanation: `[^_]` matches anything other than an underscore, so `[^_]*_[^_]*` matches anything that's not an underscore, one underscore, and then anything that's not an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- "Please_remove_this_part"
sub("([A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "Please_remove"
```

This `sub` solution defines everything before the second underscore as a capturing group and recalls it via backreference `\\1` in the replacement argument.